# pandas df creation of list within a function to be used outside the function

Tags: pandas, list, function

I want to create a list of first three values in a column in a df, but this df is created within a function and will be called several times with different input variables. Every time I call this function, I want the new first three to be added on to the list of old first three. Then I would like to be able to use this list outside this function, as in input list while calling a different function.

So within the function, with the first call, the df that is created is like below:

```
col1     col2
 A        1
 B        2
 C        3
 D        4
```

And the list should look like this:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

then with the next iteration with changed input variable, the table will look like this

```
col1     col2
 E        5
 F        6
 G        7
 H        8
 I        9
```

then the list should look like this:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

then I should be able to use this list outside this function (as an input for a different function). Could someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What have you tried and how is the function looks like?

Comment: I have only been able to accomplish the creation of the df within the function. It is a simple function which is creating a df from sorted columns. With each call, I am sorting it on different column and dropping the rest. I need to do it this way to help the rest of my program

Answer (score 0):

You can collect as list your column

```
my_list = df[col1].tolist()
```

then get the three first element

```
selected_items = my_list[:2]
```

then concat with your previous list

```
previous_list = previous_list + selected_items
```

obviouly previous list should be initialized before.

you can do these process at each new iterration of your process.

Comment: thanks. How can I access the final list outside the function?

Comment: I was supposing to do this outside the function when you can access the output (the dataframe)
else you can return a tuple of the list and the dataframe

Comment: how can I do that please?

Comment: if you still need answer please provide more information on how you retrieve the data return by the fucntion, where do you call the function (in a for loop?)